# Python 3.8 path on Windows 10

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, path

I have problems to set the Python environment in Windows 10.
The default path of Python installation is 
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe`

But when I run in `CMD` or `PowerShell` does not locate the Python command.
Any idea?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments, or is this a situation where it would unfeasible or impractical?

Comment: you could add to `PATH` folder `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32` (without `python.exe`).

Comment: @Matthew,  the cmd did not recognize the command 'Python'

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, I use Virtualenv on Linux, but on W10 is the first time

Comment: @GinoMempin, the path is already put in the windows virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

you need to add your python installation path to environmental variables where you can find  systems path variable u can add ur location followed by ';' and path of your installation.

or  simply open python ide then follow this code.

```
import sys
print(sys.path) #see if u can find ur installation location path in the output if not
sys.path.append('enter your installation path here')
```

enjoy!!
hope it solved your question.

Comment: True, I forgot to comment that path is included in environment variables and even so, W10 doesn't recognize it!
Thank you!